# Weird smooth shading

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, light, shaders

I'm fairly new to Blender 3D and I'm making a model.
After applying smooth shading to my character's face, I get weird lighting.

Things that I've tried to resolve this problem:

- Recalculate normals ( all normals are facing the right way )
- Use Auto smooth
- Apply edge split modifier

[image]

[image]

Comment: Weird lighting in rendered view? Or is that textured view?

Comment: Object, textured and rendered.

Comment: many NGons? your face could use more topology anyway.

Comment: There are no NGons, but my face does contain some few.

Comment: you'd better add loops around mouth and eyes and cut long faces.

Comment: There _are_ ngons and tris as well. The edge split modifier can only do so much, try tweaking the angle or reworking your mesh to get rid of the pinched areas and get more even spaced quads.

Comment: The topology you are using has very large polygons that don't really adjust to the contours of the mask you are trying to do. No amount of smooth shading is going to make it easier. I recommend reading this page to get some ideas on the topology of a face: http://www.thundercloud-studio.com/index.php?page=tutorial/ModelingTutorial/headModeling

Comment: If you want a really quick, short term fix, try add a subsurf modifier (ctrl + 1)

Comment: I don't see any shading problems. This is how it should look. the problem is the model is very low poly and has less than perfect topology.

Comment: @ChristyJames Thanks for the tip! It did work for a great extent and removed some of the uneven shading spots.

Answer (score 1):

In the Properties Editor, go to Object Data > Geometry Data > Clear Custom Split Normal Data

[Shading in object mode differ from sculpting mode?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35185/shading-in-object-mode-differ-from-sculpting-mode)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to add a *Subdivision Surface* modifier and increase the subdivisions to 2-3, you won't have this shading problem then.