# Glossy material rendering black, in a scene with environment and emission lighting

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Having a bit of an issue, just messing around with some game models. And whenever I apply a glossy shader it renders black, just for the car/tires model (pre modeled). Any other objects (newly created) render the glossy just fine. I have a plane with an emission shader as well in the scene.

Thanks!

EDIT: [.blend file](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=44046)

[image]

Comment: That's because of custom split normals, [related](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39646/what-does-it-mean-when-my-angle-setting-under-auto-smooth-greyed-out). Once they're deleted / unused the model looks as expected. Although I'm not aware of a way to render that car as glossy *and* have split normals used (if they are needed for some reason).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deactivate autosmooth in data tab and it will be ok.
[image: autosmooth]

Comment: This works as well, along with clear custom split normals. Thank you as well!