# Strange shading when joining two objects?

Tags: mesh, objects, lighting

I have two separate objects that I want to join together, both with no modifiers and applied transformations/scales, but when I join them I get the shading on the model starts to look weird.

These are the two separated objects

[image: Object 1]

[image: Object 2]

And these are the objects joined together. Is there a way to fix the strange shading that occurs here? Thanks

[image: Joined Objects]

Comment: hello could you please share your file if Marty's answer didn't work? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: A little late, but this may help solve your problem, it did for me. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39646/what-does-it-mean-when-my-angle-setting-under-auto-smooth-greyed-out

Answer (score 2):

It looks like one of the objects was originally smooth shaded while the other was not.  Select the joined object in object mode, Right Click and select *Shade Smooth* from the menu.  Then go to the Properties editor → Object Data Properties and open the *Normals* panel and select *Auto Smooth*.

Comment: The model in the last image of my post is smooth shaded and has auto smooth enabled, I probably should have stated that in the post.

Comment: It sometimes happens that if you join a mesh that is not smooth shaded to a mesh that is that not all of the polys become smooth shaded.  Did you apply smooth shading after you joined the meshes?

Comment: Both meshes had smooth shading before I joined them

Comment: Then please share your blend file in your question ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the normals of the joined object. In *Edit Mode*, press: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> or go to object menu *Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside*