# Buggy shading on a simple model

Tags: modeling, light

I have a model with no complex shading, only Lambert diffuse and a texture. I have these weird black spots and buggy lighting that appears when exported to a game engine too. How do I fix it?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzBoGW_cEeBcVHhqZDU1V3RyTFk/view?usp=sharing
[image]

Comment: Those are normals issues try fixing it using Ctrl + N

Comment: If recalculating the normals doesn't fix it, is it possible you could upload the .blend?

Comment: Ctrl + N just messes up the normals. It doesn't seem to work with backface culling. It also doesn't fix the shading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem which causes this unexpected result is normals splitted in a wrong way.

1. In Edit mode with all selected access Specials menu with <kbd>W</kbd> and choose *Remove Doubles*.
2. With all still selected press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate normals.
3. Then in order to get rid of ugly artifacts caused by smooth shading normals should be splitted (see [How to smooth shade an object while retaining hard edges?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/734/how-to-smooth-shade-an-object-while-retaining-hard-edges)). In Properties Editor > Object data tab in *Normals* rollout you can see that *Autosmooth* option is turned on but angle setting is greyed out. See [What does it mean when my Angle setting under Auto Smooth greyed out ?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39646/what-does-it-mean-when-my-angle-setting-under-auto-smooth-greyed-out).

   In the same tab open Geometry Data rollout; button *Clear Custom Split Normals Data* is active, so data is  present.

   [image: Custom split normals data location]

   You can use 2 ways: clear custom split normals and set up either *Autosmooth* angle or **Edge Split** modifier, *or* leave custom split normals as they are (e.g. if they should be preserved) and uncheck *Autosmooth* option.

---

See also:

- [Shading in object mode differ from sculpting mode?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35185/shading-in-object-mode-differ-from-sculpting-mode)
- Editing custom split normals [using Normal Edit modifier](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Mont29/Foundation/Split_Vertex_Normals/Custom_Split_Normals_Manual).