# How can I remove shadows from sides of the objects?

Tags: shadows

On the sides of certain objects, it would show these ugly shadows on the side. I have tried to disable the shadow option from certain properties but they did nothing. If there is any advice or solutions of this issue, any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: if your sun light is coming straight from the top, only the top faces will be lit. You have three basic options: 1-Make the source larger. 2-Create an environment that illuminates the shadows (just like the light reflected on the atmosphere illuminates the areas not directly illuminated by the sun) or 3- Add more light sources. Just keep in mind that every source will create its own new shadows. In any case you need to learn how to light a scene... there are plenty of so called "tutorials" for that online.

Comment: Shadows are the absence of light, si It is not about "removing" shadows, but about "adding" light.

Comment: One more thing to check is if the models you are importing have cusom split normals read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47142/buggy-shading-on-a-simple-model/47423#47423