# Blender weird shading

Tags: import, shaders, unreal-engine

I'm having this problem [image]

If you notice que is this weird shading on the curve , how can I fix it? i dont really know what it is, I've already tried flipping the normals but nothing, what else can i try?
thanks!
P.S. the mesh was imported from unreal, because in unreal it shows this problem
[image]

Comment: did you try recalculating normals by going into edit mode, selecting the entire mesh, and then pressing ctrl + N?

Comment: yes! i also tried manyallu flipping one by one but nothing its still the same issue just the darkes area inverts

Comment: did you try removing doubles?

Comment: yes actually i did't before exporting it to unreal

Comment: also if i smooth shade it it looks like this

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAbCA.png

Comment: This looks like iimported custom split normals wrongly shading the mesh, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35185/shading-in-object-mode-differ-from-sculpting-mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, if you are importing from blender to unreal, and get the degenerate tangent base problem ujst uncheck this [image]

the first two options
P.S. sorry, my unreal engine is in spanish

Comment: sorry for the extremely late selection, didnt notice this open thread i got overflowed with work, sorry man but yeah, this was exactly the same i did to fix my issue!