# Object appears Black while rendering ? while other objects look normal

Tags: rendering, materials

When I try to render, one of objects on scene remains almost black like it doesnt recive any light, while other objects are normal. Why would the object (on photo its giraffe)not react to light, and what would be the solution ?
Will be thankful for any tips :)
[image]

Comment: could you share your file or at least some vertices of your object?

Comment: https://ufile.io/rxz9f    Here is file, I just deleted half of giraffe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: actually my first answer was not accurate, you have an *Auto Smooth* enabled, in order to make your *Auto Smooth* work you need to go in the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Geometry Data* and press the *Clear Custom Split Normals Data* button.

As explained [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35185/shading-in-object-mode-differ-from-sculpting-mode): "Your model has a custom split normal data (probably due to a normal edit modifier that has been applied or because the mesh was made with another software...) that keep some face shading in that way."

[image]

Comment: It works! i did make it in Maya oryginally. Thank you for all usefull information