# Problem: Wireframe on object with modifiers, autosmooth problem

Tags: modeling, modifiers, wireframe

I have Blender 2.8 and I want to ask two questions.
I am trying make simple model of "sci-fi bulldozer".

[image]

Q.1 - Is available to turn off wireframe on objects with modifiers? If i turn off wireframe (picture), the wireframe stay on objects that contain modifiers. The wireframe will disappear on objects without modifier.

[image]

Q.2 - Does anybody know why i cant use "auto smooth" on some objects? The value in auto smooth is grey (no modifiers, normals are ok, vertices merge applied…). It is OK on some objects…

[image]

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: At least with your second question, i've browsed a bit, and found several people with the same issue. Maybe try looking at these? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35185/shading-in-object-mode-differ-from-sculpting-mode, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39646/what-does-it-mean-when-my-angle-setting-under-auto-smooth-greyed-out/39872

Answer (score 0):

Very thank you for the comment, that helps me solve the Q.2

**Solutions for my problem:**

*Q.1:* You can set wireframe for each object separately. You can find it for each object in:

[image]

Q.2: Go to Properties editor > Object Data panel > Geometry Data and click on Clear Custom Split Normals Data to re-enable the angle setting.